# Getting a pop-up with attribute info from WMS

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geoserver, wms

I am new to javascript and web mapping and after searching through the internet, this is still not clear to me.

I am building a basic web map using leaflet. I have three layers (streets, states and street info) that I uploaded to Geoserver as shapefiles. My script shows them correctly and I can show and hide them with a checkbox control.

Now, I want to be able to click on any feature from the map and get a pop-up with the info from a certain field from that single feature. For example, clicking on a street line and getting it's name, which is stored in the shapefile in Geoserver. Also, it would be great if you could only get the data if the shapefile was shown and not hidden.

I have read that you can do that with GetFeatureInfo, but since I still don't have much experience with JavaScript, I have no idea on how to integrate that on my script. I have tried several times and all I get is a white window, which it is due to a wrong way of using GetFeatureInfo. How do you integrate that tool?

This is my script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<head>
    <title>Aguascalientes</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.2/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.2/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" ></script>

<style>
    #map { 
    width: 100%;
    height: 850px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888;}
</style>
</head>
    <body>
        <div id = "map"></div>
<script>

var map = L.map('map').
setView([21.885256, -102.291568],
15);

var osm = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://cloudmade.com">CloudMade</a>',
    maxZoom: 18
}).addTo(map);

var muni = L.tileLayer.wms("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Visor/wms?", {
    layers: 'muni4326',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
    opacity:1,
    version: '1.1.0',
    attribution: "Geoserver"
    }).addTo(map)

var vialidad = L.tileLayer.wms("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Visor/wms?", {
    layers: '01vialid4326',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
    opacity:1,
    version: '1.1.0',
    attribution: "Geoserver"
    }).addTo(map)

var numext = L.tileLayer.wms("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Visor/wms?", {
    layers: '01numext4326',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
    opacity:1,
    version: '1.1.0',
    attribution: "Geoserver"
    }).addTo(map)


var baseLayers = {
"Base:": osm  
};

var overlayers = {
"States": muni,
"Streets": vialidad, 
"Street info": numext
};

L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlayers,{collapsed:true}).addTo(map);

</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Thank you in advance

**EDIT**:

I have been trying to understand how to use this:
https://gist.github.com/rclark/6908938

I created a file named L.TileLayer.BetterWMS.js and I directly inserted the script found in github, and it doesn't work. I am guessing I have to modify some parts of the script, but I don't know what. Also, after creating that file, I called it as seen in this example:

```
var map = L.map('map').
setView([21.885256, -102.291568],
15);

var osm = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://cloudmade.com">CloudMade</a>',
    maxZoom: 18
}).addTo(map);

var muni = L.tileLayer.BetterWMS("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Visor/wms?", {
    layers: 'muni4326',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
    opacity:1,
    version: '1.1.0',
    attribution: "Geoserver"
    }).addTo(map)

var vialidad = L.tileLayer.BetterWMS("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Visor/wms?", {
    layers: '01vialid4326',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
    opacity:1,
    version: '1.1.0',
    attribution: "Geoserver"
    }).addTo(map)

var numext = L.tileLayer.BetterWMS("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Visor/wms?", {
    layers: '01numext4326',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
    opacity:1,
    version: '1.1.0',
    attribution: "Geoserver"
    }).addTo(map)


var baseLayers = {
"Base:": osm  
};

var overlayers = {
"States": muni,
"Streets": vialidad, 
"Street info": numext
};

L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlayers,{collapsed:true}).addTo(map);

</script>
```

This still doesn't work. I am guessing I am making a mistake in something very basic, but I can't figure out where.

**EDIT 2:**

To be more clear, when I use a regular `L.TileLayer.wms(url...)`, the layers show perfectly on the map, but obviously, they don't do the GetFeatureInfo since I'm not referring to the L.TileLayer.BetterWMS.js. As soon as I change it to  `L.TileLayer.BetterWMS(url...)` the layers stop showing on the map and an error shows: `Uncaught TypeError: this.callInitHooks is not a function at Function.e [as BetterWMS] (leaflet.js:5) at leaflet.html:32`.

I checked the links that you guys put on the comment section and they don't seem to be solving that error.

This is the full script that is giving me the error:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<head>
    <title>Visor aguascalientes</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.2/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.2/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" ></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="L.TileLayer.BetterWMS.js"></script>    
<style>
    #map { 
    width: 100%;
    height: 850px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888;}
</style>
</head>
    <body>
        <div id = "map"></div>
<script>


var map = L.map('map').
setView([21.885256, -102.291568],
15);

var osm = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://cloudmade.com">CloudMade</a>',
    maxZoom: 18
}).addTo(map);

var muni = L.TileLayer.BetterWMS("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Visor/wms?", {
    layers: 'muni4326',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
    opacity:1,
    version: '1.1.0',
    attribution: "Geoserver"
    }).addTo(map)

var vialidad = L.TileLayer.BetterWMS("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Visor/wms?", {
    layers: '01vialid4326',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
    opacity:1,
    version: '1.1.0',
    attribution: "Geoserver"
    }).addTo(map)

var numext = L.TileLayer.BetterWMS("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Visor/wms?", {
    layers: '01numext4326',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
    opacity:1,
    version: '1.1.0',
    attribution: "Geoserver"
    }).addTo(map)


var baseLayers = {
"Base:": osm  
};

var overlayers = {
"Municipio": muni,
"Calles": vialidad, 
"Portales": numext
};

L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlayers,{collapsed:true}).addTo(map);

</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Have you looked at : https://gist.github.com/rclark/6908938

Comment: @Pogrindis Yes, I did, but I don't quite understand how to get it to work

Comment: how about https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138154/geoserver-popups-in-leaflet or https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177444/wms-getfeatureinfo-and-leaflet - really need more information about the errors you are getting to narrow it down,

Comment: Thanks for the links, @IanTurton, but they don't seem to solve my problem. I edited my question a second time to show the exact error that I am getting. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Okay, I solved it. The problem was that the plugin is not compatible with the latest Leaflet version. Using an older version fixed it.